# Using SetWindowsHookEx. in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, hook, setwindowshookex

This function is getting me crazy! I am trying to use SetWindwosHookEx to avoid some keystrokes from the user, but I can't make it work properly.

I have been looking around many code on the web but I don't understand why it is not working for me. Firstly, it was because I was using Excel 2010 (64 bit) and my code wasn't for it, but now I don't know.

Basically, I have created a simple code which shows me a message when I pull "g" but what it is happening is Excel crashes when a pull any key. It doesn't crash when I run the code step by step but if I pull "g" the message appears three times!

This is my code:

```
#If Win64 Then

Public Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As LongPtr, ByVal lpFn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As LongPtr) As LongPrt
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As LongPtr, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As LongPtr) As Integer
Private hWndPPT As LongPtr
Private HookHandle As LongPtr

'ADICIONAL
Private Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" (ByVal hDlg As LongPrt, ByVal nIDDlgItem As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As LongPtr, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As LongPtr) As LongPtr



#Else
Public Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpFn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Public Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private hWndPPT As Long
Private HookHandle As Long

'ADICIONAL
Private Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" (ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

#End If



'Constants to be used in our API functions
'Private Const EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR = &HCC
'Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const WH_KEYBOARD = 2
'Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0

'Private hHook As Long


Public Sub RemoveHook()
    UnhookWindowsHookEx (HookHandle)
End Sub

Sub SetHook()
#If Win64 Then
Dim lThreadID As LongPtr
Dim lngModHwnd As LongPtr
#Else
Dim lThreadID As Long
Dim lngModHwnd As Long
#End If

lThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId
lngModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)

'Set a local hook
HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, AddressOf NewProc, 0, lThreadID)
End Sub

Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As LongPtr, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    If lngCode < HC_ACTION Then
      NewProc = CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
      Exit Function
    End If

    If wParam = 71 Then
        'MsgBox "g"
        'NewProc = 1
        wParam = 70
        'Exit Function
    End If

    'This line will ensure that any other hooks that may be in place are
    'called correctly.
    CallNextHookEx HookHandle, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function
```

Comment: You need to review your declarations - not everything should be a `LongPtr`. Those that are should be `LongPtr` and not `LongPrt`.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but which ones wouldn't be LongPtr? It is the first time that I code for 64 bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct declarations for 64bit would be:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpFn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" (ByVal hDlg As LongPtr, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
```

I can't actually see how the code you posted would run at all on 64bit.

Comment: Thanks!. Actually, it doesn't really work. The code enters in an unstoppable loop once I pull a key. I am not able to see the error, after readying information and many codes about hooks, setwindowsex, callnexthookex, etc. All the samples codes look so simple but I can't make it work

Comment: Hi again,I have made a bit of improvement and this code works almost fine, but there are a couple of problems: When I run the code, the function doesn't return the key that I am pulling so nothing is written and the "NewProc_64" function is run twice:

Comment: Should `SendDlgItemMessage ` and `GetClassName ` be `PtrSafe` as well?

Comment: @mwfearnley yes they should! I will update.